# Android getAltitude based on atmospheric pressure and sensor pressure

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sensors, pressure

I'm trying to figure out how to get my current altitude based on atmospheric pressure and sensor pressure.

```
getAltitude(SensorManager.PRESSURE_STANDARD_ATMOSPHERE, sensorPressure);
```

But this doesn't seem to work as the following error appears: `getAltitude (java.lang.String) in MainActivity cannot be appleid to (float, float);` But I can't find any documentation on what is supposed to be in the parameters.

```
public float getAltitude(String apiPressure) {
        float floatPressure = Float.parseFloat(apiPressure);
       float altitude = getAltitude(SensorManager.PRESSURE_STANDARD_ATMOSPHERE, floatPressure);
        return altitude;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling your method `getAltitude(String apiPressure)` thats defined in your package. I guess you want to call [getAltitude](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getAltitude(float,%20float)) thats defined in [android.hardware.SensorManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html):

`SensorManager.getAltitude(SensorManager.PRESSURE_STANDARD_ATMOSPHERE,pressure)`